# Why measurability does not imply continuity?

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory it is known that continuity implies measurability. But, the vice-versa doesn't hold. Can somebody explain why is this true?

Comment: Historically the motivation of measure theory was to extend integration to a broader class of functions than those whose discontinuities are  a locally finite set ( so that some functions with infinitely many discontinuities in [0,1] can still be integrated.) As Artem Mavrin's answer shows, a function may be discontinuous everywhere  and yet be measurable.

Comment: If a function $f:X \to Y$ is measurable, we know the preimage of any open set $V$ (which is also measurable in the Borel algebra on $Y$) is measurable in the Borel algebra on $X$. But the Borel algebra on $X$ also includes countable intersections of the open sets of the topology, and these may not necessarily be open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, the function $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)
= \begin{cases}
1, & x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
0, & x \notin \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}
$$
is nowhere continuous, but it is measurable (with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2):

For exemple the signum function